# how to overwrite a route in sanic when using blueprint.copy?

Tags: python, sanic

```
from sanic import Blueprint
from sanic.response import json
from sanic import Sanic

app = Sanic('test')

bpv1 = Blueprint('bpv1', version=1)

@bpv1.route('/hello')
async def root(request):
    return json('hello v1')

app.blueprint(bpv1)

bpv2 = bpv1.copy('bpv2', version=2)

@bpv2.route('/hello')
async def root(request):
    return json('hello v2')

app.blueprint(bpv2)
```

I want to overwrite the implement of route partially when they belong to different blueprint, but it raises `sanic_routing.exceptions.RouteExists`.

How can I get this target?

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from forum.

```
bpv2 = bpv1.copy("bpv2", version=2)

bpv2._future_routes = {
    route for route in bpv2._future_routes if route.uri != "/hello"
}


@bpv2.route("/hello")
async def root2(request):
    return json("hello v2")
```

**link**

https://community.sanicframework.org/t/how-to-overwrite-a-route-when-using-blueprint-copy/1067